# WPF MenuItem.IsHighlighted == false when ContextMenu and MenuItems are Transparent

Tags: wpf, hover, contextmenu, menuitem, transparent

I am trying to create a context menu which allows the user to see what is under it, and so I have made the Background for both the ContextMenu, and its MenuItems Transparent.  When the user moves the mouse over the MenuItems(hovers) they should show up due to a ControlTemplate Trigger on IsHighlighted.  The problem is that when the mouse is over the transparent part of the MenuItems the Trigger is not working.  If I change the background color of either the ContextMenu, or its MenuItems to something other than Transparent the trigger works.  I thought a Transparent Background was supposed to behave like a solid color, but in this case it is not.  Any ideas how to make this work?

```
<Window x:Class="TransparentContextMenu.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Height="600" Width="800">
    <Window.Resources>

        <ControlTemplate x:Key="contextMenuItemTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
            <Grid>
               <Polygon Points="0,0 180,0 180,30 0,30" Fill="Transparent" x:Name="Background"/>
               <Polygon Points="0,0 180,0 180,30 0,30" Opacity="0" x:Name="HoverBorder" Fill="Gray"/>
               <ContentPresenter ContentSource="Header" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            </Grid>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="1" TargetName="HoverBorder"/>
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>

        <Style x:Key="contextMenuStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ContextMenu}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ContextMenu}">
                        <Border Background="Transparent">
                            <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True"/>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>

    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid Background="Transparent">
        <Grid.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu Style="{StaticResource contextMenuStyle}">
                <MenuItem Header="Item A" Template="{StaticResource contextMenuItemTemplate}"/>
                <MenuItem Header="Item B" Template="{StaticResource contextMenuItemTemplate}"/>
                <MenuItem Header="Item C" Template="{StaticResource contextMenuItemTemplate}"/>
                <MenuItem Header="Item D" Template="{StaticResource contextMenuItemTemplate}"/>
                <MenuItem Header="Item E" Template="{StaticResource contextMenuItemTemplate}"/>
            </ContextMenu>
        </Grid.ContextMenu>
    </Grid>

</Window>

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting background to 'null' instead.